# create record with many belongs_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

In rails I have simply:

```
render json: user
```

but I want to add an additional field in the user json output that is computed based on the other fields (e.g.: fullname, computed by first name + last name)

how can I do this without having to resort to custom json views??

Answer (score 2):

For adding methods to json you can use `:methods` param. So if you have `fullname` method in your user model you can call something like:

```
render json: user.to_json(methods: :full_name)
```

Comment: Also, if you want to do more than simply call another method, look into redefining the as_json method for instances of `User`.